# Monitor turning off randomly Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: monitor

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.10 with the latest updates on my PC. I am having a issue where the monitor seems to randomly disconnect. I cannot pinpoint what is causing this issue. It can happen out of the blue, when I open thunderbird, or when I open an email in my browser, but nothing is consistent. I cannot reproduce any of these issues. It will work fine all day and nothing I don't do anything different when the issue arises.

I have installed caffeine and disabled the screensaver, disabled dpms, disabled power save settings/screen dim, and toyed with other xset commands that other's have had luck with when they had similar issues on previous versions of ubuntu.

I have not installed any additional software or drivers other than common apps through the software center. The problem occurred before any installations.

I have a dual monitor setup and both monitors lose input at the same time. The TV monitor goes to a blue screen and says "Invalid input" or "Out of range" if I recall correctly, and the other monitor switches quickly between digital and analog before eventually resting at an all black screen. Replugging the monitor doesn't do anything and the only way to get the screen back that I found is to pull the power plug and reboot, then it comes right back up.

I'm tech savvy but a linux amateur. I suppose my next step from here would be to check logs, but I don't know where to begin.

Xset -q output:

> Screen Saver:   prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
>   timeout:  0    cycle:  0 Colors:   default colormap:  0x20
>   BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff Font Path:
>   /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins DPMS
>   (Energy Star):   Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0   DPMS is Disabled

PC Specs:

> Motherboard: MSI MS-7778, Processor: AMD A10-5700 with integrated
>   Radeon HD gfx

Monitor setup:

> Dual monitors, Vizio E260MV via VGA (TV), and Samsung Syncmaster T220
>   via DVI.