# Glitching box around mouse cursor on Ubuntu 18.04 and nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, usb, 18.04, docking

Basically, I have the seem problem as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947375/lagging-box-around-mouse-cursor-on-ubuntu-17-04-and-nvidia-driver), only with Ubuntu 18.04 (thus no lightdm or sddm which could be restarted):

I am using a Dell laptop with a dell docking station, connected via USB 3. Three external displays are connected (thus I cannot get rid of the NVidia driver) and I get graphical glitches in a rectangular (probably square, hard to say) area around the mouse cursor.

Since logging in doesn't work when the laptop is connected to the docking station anyway, I always connect it after logging in, unplugging the USB 3 cable and plugging it in again doesn't change anything.

Anyone got an idea what could at least be a workaround for Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem on 18.04, but already installed lightdm before (dont remember why). You can install it as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044793/how-to-change-the-ubuntu-18-04-default-greeter). Then you can restart lightdm with

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Also if you dont want to install lightdm, you can try to reboot, it helped me once, but next power-on glitch appeared again.