# How to change the Ubuntu 18.04 default greeter?

Tags: 18.04

How can i replace the new gdm3 greeter with unity-greeter in ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it is just poorly worded. The question is about **greeters** and not **display managers** which is why I think this question is not a duplicate of the suggestions

Answer (score 6):

There is a nice little blog on doing this: [Ubuntu 18.04 – Bring back Lightdm login manager](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11767). Here are the steps summarized from the blog:

- To install use: `sudo apt-get -y install slick-greeter`
- Verify setup using: `lightdm --show-config`
- Edit the file `/etc/lightdm/slick-greeter.conf` to setup login screen wallpaper
- To revert back to GDM3 login manager use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: Why do they install slick-greeter instead of just lightdm?  Just curious.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I wondered that myself. I believe you recommended `lightdm` to me a few months ago on a different question or answer I posted. `sleek-greeter` is a more targeted name. It would be to interesting to research the birthdate of the package.

Answer (score 3):

Simply installing the `unity-greeter` package will allow you to change the greeter from `gdm3` to the ubuntu themed `lightdm` greeter.

Just run `sudo apt-get install unity-greeter lightdm --no-install-recommends`

During the configuration step you'll be faced with this window.

[image: prompt]

Press <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> and you'll get this choice selection screen

[image: prompt2]

Use the arrow keys to select `lightdm` and press enter

Comment: Yes, this works, I did it myself after installing.